# CSS class not applying to

Tags: html, css, class

I want to apply the CSS class `washes_times_links` to the html below, but for some reason it's not working.

```css
.washes_times_links a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  padding: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3b524b;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.washes_times_links a:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.washes_times_links a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px
}

.washes_times_links a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #12be9c;
}
```

```html
<p class="washes_times_links">
  <a href="http://hairactivation.com/male-hairloss-treatment/#wash-hair-less-5-days-week">1 time a week</a>
  <a href="http://hairactivation.com/male-hairloss-treatment/#wash-hair-less-5-days-week">2 times a week</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I have just converted your example code in to a StackSnippet and it works fine. Are you sure you are loading your CSS file correctly?

Comment: In what way is this not working, the rules appear to be applied as expected in your example?

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine.
Inspect on the css attributes in this: `[https://jsfiddle.net/nf0a5gq7/][1]` and you will see that all css attributes have been applied, but you're missing 'border' attribute (in .washes_times_links a:last-child), and this is why you can't see the border..

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking in a way to be useful for whoever cross by here.

**To apply style in odd/even selector:**

```
.class_name a:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
.class_name a:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}
```

**To apply radius/style for first/last selector:**

```
.class_name a:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.class_name a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

all together :

**HTML**

```
<p class="class_name">
    <a href="#1">1st row</a>
    <a href="#2">2nd row</a>
    <a href="#3">3rd row</a> 
    <a href="#4">4th row</a> 
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.class_name a {
    /* default links styles */
}
.class_name a:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
.class_name a:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #b8d1f3;
}
.classname a:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.class_name a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.class_name a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #12be9c;
}
```

[Tip: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is this answering his question?

Comment: @Rob, I believe so. waiting feedback from questioner